# SSIS Comparing 2 queries

Tags: sql, database, ssis

I am new to SSIS. 
I am supposed to create a query to get the latest update date and time from multiple tables in 2 different databases for every employee. After getting the last update date, I am supposed to compare that data from one database to another last updated date in another database and show what are the differences in both the results using SSIS. I would like to know as to how I will be able to do it. Like which topic should I learn in SSIS to get this job done?

Comment: See LookUp Task - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/lookup-transformation

Comment: @Jigar- Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty common task in SSIS. You should give a look to Lookup task and you'll figure it out how to achieve it.